# Why does MySQL version 6.0 keep throwing out errors?

Tags: mysql, database, netbeans, create-table

I am new to mySQL and Netbeans7.3.1. I got a database set up and the connection all ready to go. I created one table and that worked out alright except it wouldn't let me use auto_increment.

Now I am trying to create a table using the information from:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/mysql-refman-6.0/tutorial.html#example-auto-increment

and no matter what I do, I keep getting error messages even though I am doing just what the tutorial said.

> Error code -1, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "(" at line 2, column 13.
>   Line 1, column 1
>
> Error code -1, SQL state 42X05: Table/View 'ANIMALS' does not exist.
>   Line 8, column 1
>
> Error code -1, SQL state 42X05: Table/View 'ANIMALS' does not exist.
>   Line 13, column 1
>
> Execution finished after 0 s, 3 error(s) occurred.

What I would like to know is, is there something wrong with the code in the tutorial or is there a setting somewhere in the set up of mySQL in netbeans that I need to configure to get the code to work?

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
    grp ENUM('fish','mammal','bird') NOT NULL,
    id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (grp,id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO animals (grp,name) VALUES
    ('mammal','dog'),('mammal','cat'),
    ('bird','penguin'),('fish','lax'),('mammal','whale'),
    ('bird','ostrich');

SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY grp,id;
```

Comment: And your SQL statement is? Also: are you aware that MySQL 6.0 is not officially released and thus could still contain many bugs?

Comment: The page dones't reference Netbeans, so what are you actually doing by using Netbeans ? Your error mentions ANIMALS  while the page uses the lowercase animals, do you have some code, or SQL staements or similar to show us ?

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name No I didn't know that. I thought if it came with the version of Netbeans it would work without too many bugs.       @nos I used lowercase animals like in the tutorial but it didn't work, so I thought maybe names had to be capitalized. Like I said, I am new to this, so I was trying different stuff out. Also, I thought you could use Netbeans as a type of environment to create a mySQL database. Is that wrong?

Comment: @user1896016 No, you can use Netbeans just for that, but's it's hard for us to know exactly what youre doing & typing on your screen - especially if you're changing and trying stuff. So tell us more, and possibly copy paste _exactly_ the SQL you're running and so on.

Comment: Okay, I understand. I posted the code exactly the way I just ran it. I am am putting up everything that came up in my output page. I also noticed that it capitalizes "animals" in the output section even though it's not that way in the code. I am using Netbeans 7.3.1 which contains mySQL 6.0 (https://netbeans.org/community/releases/73/relnotes.html).

Comment: There is no NetBeans download that "comes with" MySQL. The release notes you mention are saying that the MySQL **JDBC driver** has been updated to 6.0 - which is quite irritating because there is no version 6.0 of the driver: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ You should find out which DBMS you are *really* using. The format of the error message suggests that it's **not** MySQL (If I had to to guess, I'd say it's Apache Derby aka JavaDB)

Comment: Thank you! That made a lot of sense. I actually spent some more time looking online and trying to understand what everything is. I am using JavaDB in NetBeans, but I can use SQL commands to edit the databases. I went back and tried to execute an alter table command from this site: http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-alter-table.html. I had to get rid of the generated "select*from" statement and then execute the alter table command. It worked.